# Starting node with Makefile command using gnome-terminal No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, makefile, gnome-terminal

gnome-terminal version 3.28.1 starting `nodemon` with DEBUG mode
`gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/theproject -e './node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js index.js'`

results to new window with error `No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

I think `-e` is now deprecated...

Try like:

`gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/theproject -- /bin/bash -c 'ls ;  sleep 1'`

inside the quotes (`'...'`) you can put your commands sperated by `;`'s. If you want to keep the terminal open at the end do:

`gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/theproject -- /bin/bash -c 'ls ;  sleep 1 ; echo press any key ; read'`